# how to parse a string path, and get result like this?

Tags: javascript, path

input:

**/home/ubuntu**

output:

```
[
{"name":"/","path":"/"},
{"name":"home",path:"/home"},
{"name":"ubuntu",path:"/home/ubuntu"}
]
```

how to get like this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you need:

```js
getTree = (path, nodes = []) => {
  // Split by levels
  const parts = path.split('/')
  // Remove last node from path and add to nodes array
  nodes.push({ name: parts.pop(), path })
  // Update path without last node (already added)
  path = parts.join('/')
  if (path.length) {
    // Recall method recursively if nodes left
    return getTree(path, nodes)
  } else {
    // Or add root node to array and return it
    nodes.push({ name: '/', path: '/' })
    return nodes
  }
}
```

Usage:

```js
const path = '/root/user/home/ubuntu'
console.log(getTree(path))
```

Output:

```js
[
  {name: 'ubuntu', path: '/root/user/home/ubuntu'}
  {name: 'home', path: '/root/user/home'}
  {name: 'user', path: '/root/user'}
  {name: 'root', path: '/root'}
  {name: '/', path: '/'}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly, you could do something like this

By using `Array.prototype.split()` to split the path into parts, and setting the first argument (the base) as the home and the rest of the arguments as the resultant path

```js
const string = 'home/ubuntu/test';
console.log(parse(string));
console.log(parse('home/'));
console.log(parse('/'));

function parse(str) {
    const obj = {};
    const strArr = str.split('/');

    obj['home'] = strArr[0] ? strArr[0] : '/';
    const path = strArr.slice(1, strArr.length).join('/');

    obj['path'] = path ? path : '/';
    return obj;
}
```

P.S if this is not what you meant please let me know in the comments